# extract positions 19-28 from textfile

Tags: sed, grep

Input is a textfile and I want the information contained on every line in positions 19 through 28. I don't want the whole line, just the content of these "columns".

Answer (score 2):

`cut` with `-c` option to get desired characters:

```
cut -c '19-28' file.txt
```